# Finding distance between a point and a plane

Tags: geometry

I was tasked with finding a distance between a plane of the form  $ax+by+cz +d=0$ and a  point say $(a,b)$. Now I know a way to show a plane in *Mathematica* is with

```
InfinitePlane[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {f, g}}]
```

but I dont know how to relate this to distance or anything of the sort..

any hints?

Comment: If memory serves, the distance between a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and plane $ax+by+cz +d=0$ could be calculated via the following formula:$$d_0=\frac{\left|ax_0+by_0+cz_0+d\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Upvote that server. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `RegionDistance` to find the distance from a point to a region.

```
{a, b, c, d} = {1, 2, 3, 4};

plane = ImplicitRegion[a x + b y + c z + d == 0, {x, y, z}];

RegionDistance[plane, {x0, y0, z0}] // Simplify

(* Sqrt[(4 + x0 + 2 y0 + 3 z0)^2]/Sqrt[14] *)
```

However it is probably a good idea to also read [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html) to understand how to find the answer manually.

Comment: It's a good suggestion, which does not however yield correct results

Comment: That's a bit vague, @Bak. Why not include an example of this incorrect result you speak of in your question?

Comment: @Bak1139, I've removed the `PowerExpand` - is that what you were referring to?

Comment: PowerExpand is alright, whenever I run the code I get different results all the time, so I suspect my copy of Mathematica is to blame.

Comment: note you can use `InfintePlane` here as well, `Simplify@RegionDistance[
  InfinitePlane[{{0, 1, -2}, {1, -1, -1}, {0, -2, 0}}], {x0, y0, z0}]` -> same result.